# Value for a column is the sum of the next 4 values - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
ITEM   LOCATION    QTY    WEEK 
A        X          30      1
A        X          35      2
A        X          40      3
A        X          0       4     
A        X          10      5 
A        X          19      6
```

I need to create a new column with the computation like..

```
ITEM     LOCATION   QTY    WEEK   NEW_COLUMN
 A           X      30       1    AVG(WEEK2(qty)+WEEK3(qty)+WEEK4(qty)+WEEK5(qty))
 A           X      35       2    AVG(WEEK3(qty)+WEEK4(qty)+WEEK5(qty)+WEEK6(qty))
```

similarly for all the rows....

the average of 4 weeks is fixed,it wont change.
The first week will have the average of next 4 weeks i.e., 2,3,4 and 5 `avg(35+40+0+10)`
The 2nd week will have the average of next 4 weeks i.e., 3,4,5 and 6
`avg(40+0+10+19)`.

I tried to create to bucket them based on the week number,say 
`Week 1-4 as 1`
`Week 5-8 as 2`.
and tried to do the process,but i am getting the same avg for the each buckets,say same value for 1,2,3,4 line items..

Comment: What is the average based on for Week 6 (since there are no greater weeks?)

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? The Lead() function in 2012 could be useful.

Comment: It goes on like that,For week 6 it would be avg(week7+week8+week9+week10)

Comment: i am using 2012 sqlserver..

Comment: i tried Lead(),but i am not able to restrict it to next 4 consecutive values

Comment: Ok, but the question of @Mark Brackett was what about the last week (no matter it is 6th ot 52th or 200th).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joining to the same table with a clause restricting the `Weeks` to be within your range should work. You'll have to decide what the right answer is for the last weeks (which won't have 4 weeks afterwards) and either `COALESCE` the right answer or `INNER JOIN` them out.

```
 SELECT T.Item, T.Location, T.Week, AVG(N.Qty) as New_Column
 FROM Table T
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table N ON
     T.Item = N.Item
     AND T.Location = N.Location
     AND N.Week BETWEEN (T.Week + 1) AND (T.Week + 4)
 GROUP BY T.Item, T.Location, T.Week
```

Comment: He needs average and you calculate only SUM?

Comment: You need to convert qty in decimal value, or you'll lost fraction part

Comment: Hey @MarkBrackett but there is another issue with it..my data is now like.,
ITEM   LOCATION    QTY    WEEK  YEAR
A        X                       30      1            2015
A        X                        35      2           2015            
A        X                       40      3           2015
A        X                       0       4                2015  
A        X                       40      1        2016
A        X                       0       2               2016
A        X                       10      3            2016
A        X                       19      4           2016

Comment: So if i bring in the years into this..say if want the avg of week 51 in 2015,then it will be like..
WEEK 51 = AVG(Week52(2015)+Week53(2015)+Week1(2016)+Week2(2016))

I tried it summarize the table by years,but i am getting it rite.

Comment: @ShyamPandian - You can use a derived table with ROW_NUMBER; or do (Years * 52 + Week) to get an unbroken contiguous sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
T1.ITEM, 
T1.LOCATION, 
T1.WEEK, 
MAX(T1.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY, 
AVG(T2.QUANTITY) AS NEW_COLUMN 
FROM TBL t1 LEFT JOIN TBL t2 
ON 
T1.ITEM=T2.ITEM AND T1.LOCATION=T2.LOCATION 
AND T2.WEEKNUMBER >T1.WEEK AND T2.WEEKNUMBER<T1.WEEK+5
GROUP BY t1.ITEM, t1.LOCATION, T1.WEEK
```

Answer (score 2):

You can self-join to the same table 4 times:

```
select t0.item, t0.location, t0.qty, t0.week,
    (t1.qty + t2.qty + t3.qty + t4.qty) / 4.0
from [table] t0
left join [table] t1 on t0.item = t1.item and t0.location = t1.location 
    and t1.week = t0.week + 1
left join [table] t2 on t0.item = t2.item and t0.location = t2.location 
    and t2.week = t0.week + 2
left join [table] t3 on t0.item = t3.item and t0.location = t3.location 
    and t3.week = t0.week + 3
left join [table] t4 on t0.item = t4.item and t0.location = t4.location 
    and t4.week = t0.week + 4
```

You can simplify those joins if you have a better key available for the table.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/ 4.0`, @Joel Coehoorn?

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov I made the change, but it depends on what data type the qty field has.

Comment: I agree @Joel Coehoorn. I just want to remark if the AVG have to return float data we need to delete by .0.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the other answers work fine, but with 2012 it should be really easy:

```
SELECT *,New_Column = (SUM(Qty) OVER(ORDER BY Week ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 5 FOLLOWING)*1.0)/4
FROM Table1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1463/5/0)

If it's by `item` and `location` then just add `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT *,New_Column = (SUM(Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY Item, Location ORDER BY Week ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 5 FOLLOWING)*1.0)/4
FROM Table1
```

To filter out records that don't have 4 subsequent records, you could use `LEAD()` for filtering:

```
;with cte AS (    SELECT *,New_Column = (SUM(Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY Item, Location ORDER BY Week ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 5 FOLLOWING)*1.0)/4
                          ,Lead4Col = LEAD(week,5) OVER(PARTITION BY Item,Location ORDER BY Week)
                  FROM Table1
            )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE Lead4Col IS NOT NULL
```

You could also use `COUNT(Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY Item, Location ORDER BY Week ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 5 FOLLOWING)` instead of `LEAD()` to do your filtering to when 4 subsequent weeks exist.

Edit:  I think you actually want to exclude this week from the calculation, so adjusted slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same as earlier, but insted SUM()/4 better to use AVG

Also I use *1.0 to make decimal value from qty, cause if it's integer - you'll lost fraction part after AVG operation.

```sql
SELECT *, 
       new_column = ( Avg(qty * 1.0) 
                      over( 
                        PARTITION BY item, location 
                        ORDER BY week ROWS BETWEEN 1 following AND 5 following 
                      )
                    ) 
FROM  table1
```

Comment: Almost nothing new. The same what offer Hart CO earlier, but he use Sum and /4 and I offer to use avg to count the average.

Answer (score 0):

```
with x as 
(select *, lead(qty) over(partition by item order by week) as next_1 from tablename)
, y as 
(select *, lead(qty) over(partition by item order by week) as next_2 from x)
, z as 
(select *, lead(qty) over(partition by item order by week) as next_3 from y)
, w as 
(select *, lead(qty) over(partition by item order by week) as next_4 from z)
select item, location, qty, week, (next_1+next_2+next_3+next_4)/4 as new_column from w
```

This uses recursive cte's. `lead` function selects the next row's qty value. When you go from the first `cte` to the fourth, a new column gets added each time, so you will have all the next 4 week's values at the end. Then you just take the average.